# JavaScript array in SharePoint different in length from html?

Tags: javascript

Apologies for deliberately cross-posting, but I have an issue where a JavaScript array in SharePoint is showing a different length from HTML (and an incorrect one!)

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373688/javascript-array-giving-different-length-inside-sharepoint-compared-to-html-ind)

---

Updated original to add test javascript

Comment: Can you make a JS fiddle up of your code please, an example piece of HTML and the JavaScript. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Could you please give us an example on this code? It's hard to help you when we don't have the code

Comment: not sure the actual code is of any help...SP2010 is returning the SAME javascript array with a different length?  The array is identical, the "code" is identical (it's C&P'd) - its just a <script> with an array in there.

Comment: It would be a lot of help BlueChippy. From the information provided it isn't possible to ascertain the reason.

Comment: The main reason for this, is that you could be using a variable that is already defined, and you are redefining it. From the code we would be able see that, and correct it possibly by scoping your javascript variables properly.

Comment: Added test script to original post...note that the original screenshot shows the variable name.

Comment: Your test script is giving me the correct number(7) in JSFiddle as well as in SP2010.

Comment: Still gives me 8 in SP2010.  7 in JSFiddle, 7 in IE-F12, "alert", etc from an HTML page.  Something screwy going on with SP2010.  I copied that scripts from SP2010, so it's the source of the other tests...they ALL come back 7!

Comment: Well, what I have done to test it: Created a blank new Site Page, insert Form Webpart and copy/paste the code you provided. Is this what you did, too?

Comment: Yes, tried it in a NewForm.aspx (fails), new site page (works) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your javascript code ;) rergardless if its a c&p job! what works for one doesnt mean it would work for another.

Javascript is tempramental in code where sharepoint is not as bad!

As for your code do you have a trailing comma in your code??

this guy explains the issue in more detail :) cba to re-invent the wheel lol

> No. IE incorrectly interprets a single trailing comma as an elision
>   and adds one to the length when it shouldn't (ECMA-262 sect. 11.1.4).

[Length of Array Differs In Internet Explorer With Trailing Comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541163/javascript-length-of-array-in-internet-explorer/6541189#6541189).

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, checked for trailing comma but can't see one in either actual or test code...could SP be adding one somehow?